# Open file with .gpx extension from email attachment in Android

Tags: android

One of the features that my app has is ability to import .gpx files from sdcard (file) or email attachment. i didnt have any problem making it work for only working with files on sdcard, but with opening attachments i have a problem. the only solution with opening attachments that works for me is to put in manifest: **data android:mimeType="text/xml"** for activity that imports .gpx files. but with this solution my app can also open all the xml files, wich is something i dont want. i want it to be able to open only .gpx attachments. can somebody help :-)

Manifest code:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".TracksListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity that imports .gpx file

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent == null)
        return;
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri == null)
        return;

    String scheme = uri.getScheme();

    if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(scheme))
    {
        final File file = new File(uri.getPath());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, file.getName());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, file.getAbsolutePath());

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.import_gpx)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.would_you_like_to_import_the_gpx) + file.getName() + " ?")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        InputStream is;

                        try
                        {
                            is = new FileInputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                            return;
                        }

                        GpxParser gpxParser = new GpxParser(TracksListActivity.this);
                        gpxParser.importGpxFromFile(is);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();
    }
    else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(scheme))
    {
        final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.import_gpx)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.would_you_like_to_import_the_gpx_attach))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        InputStream is;

                        try
                        {
                            is = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                            return;
                        }

                        GpxParser gpxParser = new GpxParser(TracksListActivity.this);
                        gpxParser.importGpxFromFile(is);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the scenario for `ability to import .gpx files from sdcard`? What are the user actions?

Comment: sry for not making myself more clear :-) what i ment was, user goes to the file explorer and on clicking file with extension .gpx window opens "Complete action using" and there among other apps is my app which has ability to open that file type. If user chooses my app, in activity i grab the file path of the file and parse that .gpx file to my database. I want to do the same thing when i open the attachment in gmail. With this solution that works but i want it to limit it only to attachments with .gpx extension.

Comment: Which one is involved when the user uses gmail for saving an attachment: scheme_file or scheme_content? I was confused because of `my app has is ability to import .gpx files`. Of course your app can handle .gpx files. But what you want is register your app so your app/activity gets started upon users selecting files using other apps.

Comment: scheme_content is for gmail

Comment: Can you try the Email app? As you were using the Gmail app I understood.

Comment: Do you have a solution? after 8 years...